# How drawing figure attache by tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How drawing attache figure by `Tikz`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = .6pt,font=\footnotesize]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[right,below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above,left]{$y$};
\node at (-.2,-.2) {$O$};
\draw[line width =1pt] (.25,.5) .. controls (1.5,-1.5) and (1.5,.5) .. (3.75,3);
\draw (.5,.25) node[above]{$A$} -- (.5,-1);
\draw (1.5,-.5) node[above]{$B$} -- (1.5,-1);
\draw (2.5,.5) node[above]{$C$} -- (2.5,-1);
\draw (3.5,2.5) node[above]{$D$} -- (3.5,-1);
\draw (4.5,1.5) node[above]{$E$} -- (4.5,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you name the five nodes `a`, `b`, etc., then you can use

```
\draw [shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] plot [smooth] coordinates {(a.south)(b.south)(c.south)(d.south)(e.south)};
```

as an approximation.

Note one thing: When you do `node [right, below]`, the `below` setting overwrites `right`, so `right` doesn't have an effect. I.e. they're not cumulative. What actually happens is that `right` sets `anchor=west`, and `below` sets `anchor=north`, and a `node` can only have one `anchor`. The anchor determines which point of the node is placed at the given coordinate. The same thing happens for `above, left`.

If you do want the `$x$` node below and right of the end point of the axis, use `node [below right] {$x$}`. The `below right` key sets `anchor=north west`, meaning that the top left corner of the node is placed at the end of the path.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = .6pt,font=\footnotesize]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[left]{$y$};
\node at (-.2,-.2) {$O$};

\draw (.5,.25) node (a) [above]{$A$} -- (.5,-1);
\draw (1.5,-.5) node (b) [above]{$B$} -- (1.5,-1);
\draw (2.5,.5) node (c) [above]{$C$} -- (2.5,-1);
\draw (3.5,2.5) node (d) [above]{$D$} -- (3.5,-1);
\draw (4.5,1.5) node (e) [above]{$E$} -- (4.5,-1);

\draw [shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] plot [smooth] coordinates {(a.south)(b.south)(c.south)(d.south)(e.south)};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

For fun, a slight variation using a loop to draw the vertical lines and add nodes:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{alphalph} % for \alphalph and \AlphAlph, converting number to letter

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width = .6pt,font=\footnotesize]
\draw[->] (-1,0) -- (6,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1) -- (0,4) node[above]{$y$};
\node [below left] {$O$};

\foreach [count=\j] \y in {.25, -.5, .5, 2.5, 1.5}
  \draw (-.5+\j,-1) -- (-.5+\j,\y)
        coordinate [label=above:$\AlphAlph{\j}$] (\alphalph{\j});

\draw [shorten <=-5mm, shorten >=-5mm] plot [smooth] coordinates {(a)(b)(c)(d)(e)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```